# How can I declare a function returning a type from a Typescript-enabled library in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm using a library (Axios) that has Typescript declarations included in its package.

I'd like to declare a function that takes an AxiosResponse (declared in the library's .d.ts file) as a parameter. I have the following:

```
function persistEvents(response: AxiosResponse) {
  ...
}
```

However, in VS code, I'm encountering the error "Cannot find name 'AxiosResponse'".

What do I need to do to be able to declare a function parameter or return that's from my library?

Comment: did you export the function? or declare a proper namespace?

Comment: `import { AxiosResponse } from "axios";`

Comment: Thanks! @cartant 's answer worked. Feel free to post a full answer. For future readers, this blog-post was a really really useful guide: [Typescript Typings - The Complete Guide To Type Definitions: \@types, Compiler Opt-In Types: When To Use Each and Why ?](http://blog.angular-university.io/typescript-2-type-system-how-do-type-definitions-work-in-npm-when-to-use-types-and-why-what-are-compiler-opt-in-types/)

Comment: If you also want to use Axios in this file, you can import both by doing `import Axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To reference types declared in another package, you will need to import them into the `.ts` or `.d.ts` file in which you wish to use them.

Adding the following import should solve your problem:

```ts
import { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
```